# Replacing space with dash "-" in Javascript & HTML for Vite

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I have a website called [Vite (Flash Engine)](http://vitemulti.weebly.com) and it has a textbox where you type something in and it takes you to a website.
*Example: Type "Google" it will take you to vitemulti.weebly.com/google which will then take you to https://www.google.com*

A dash will put a **%20** in the URL which doesn't work with the code & Weebly.

There are similar questions on this website which don't seem to work.

```js
function CheckPassword() {
  var input=document.type.input.value;
  input = input.replace(/\s/g , "-");
  location.href = input+'/';
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="ingen_javascript.htm" 
  onsubmit="CheckPassword();return false;" name="type">
<pre>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type in a website" name="input" list="autocomplete" onkeyup="document.getElementById('identifier').value=this.value.replace(/\s/g,'-').toLowerCase();" autofocus>


</pre>
<input type="submit" value="Vite" 
  onclick="CheckPassword();return false;" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;" hidefocus="true" onclick="move()">
</form>
```

Is it possible if I added something to the [script](http://vitemulti.weebly.com/files/theme/CheckPassword.js) that replaces spaces with a dash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="ingen_javascript.htm" 
  onsubmit="CheckPassword();return false;" name="type">
<pre>
<input type="text" placeholder="Type in a website" name="input" list="autocomplete" onkeyup="document.getElementsByName('input')[0].value=this.value.replace(/\s/g,'-').toLowerCase();" autofocus>


</pre>
<input type="submit" value="Vite" 
  onclick="CheckPassword();return false;" style="height: 0px; width: 0px; border: none; padding: 0px;" hidefocus="true" onclick="move()">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript>
function CheckPassword() {
  var input=document.getElementsByName('input')[0].value;
  input = input.replace(/\s/g , "-");
  console.log(input);
  location.href = input+'/';
}
</script>
```